# Try, except, back to try?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, error-handling

I want to use try and except, how do I go from except back to try? The code goes like this:

try:
    face detection function
expect NameError:
    print('no face detected')

Now here is where I want to go back to the try statement in order to keep searching for the face. Is there a way to go back to the try statement or is there another way to do this that doesn't include using try and except?

Comment: Generally if you want to run some code multiple times, you use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could always encase that in a loop, like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        face_detection_function()
        break
    except NameError:
        print('no face detected')
```

Now to be honest, I am not sure you should rely on exceptions for this. You could just have your function return an extra boolean variable indicating when a face was found.